# Jacoco-agent build failure, can't overwrite the file

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I have integrated the jacoco in the multimodule project but during the build generation the project is failing with jacoco-agent.properties overwrite error.

res.jar already contain jacoco-agent.properties can't overwrite

The jacoco plugin is applied at the project level

subprojects {

afterEvaluate{ project-> project.apply from : 'jacoco.gradle'}....}